# SHELL, Save echo's output in to a file (c code)?

Tags: c, shell, unix

I was trying to write a shell program(in c) and came across the following problem. Can any one please tell me how can I save the output of an `echo` in to a file. For example, some one might type in `echo document_this > foo1` then I want to save `document_this` in to a file name foo1.

```
if(strcmp(myargv[0],"echo") == 0)
{
   printf("Saving: %s in to a file", myargv[1]);
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. can't use `#include <fstream>`, anything else I should use? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate the check for redirection from the command itself.  First, loop to check for redirection:

```
FILE* output = stdin;

for (int i = 0; i < myargc - 1; ++i)
    if (strcmp(myargv[i], ">") == 0)
    {
         output = fopen(myargv[i + 1], "w");
         myargc = i; // remove '>' onwards from command...
         break;
    }

// now output will be either stdin or a newly opened file 

// evaluate the actual command

if (strcmp(myargv[0], "echo") == 0)
    for (int i = 1; i < myargc; ++i) // rest of arguments...
    {
         fwrite(myargv[i], strlen(myargv[i]), 1, output);

         // space between arguments, newline afterwards
         fputc(i < myargc - 2 ? ' ' : '\n', output);
    }
else if (... next command ...)
    ...

// close the output file if necessary
if (output != stdin)
    fclose(output);
```

Adding proper error checking is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice explanation. but the fputc(..) function doesn't seems to work though. It says "error: too few arguments to function ‘fputc’

Comment: @NewGuy: Well, as the error message tells you, it's missing an argument, which if you look at the documentation (http://linux.die.net/man/3/fputc), you can easily see that the missing argument should be `output`.

Comment: @NewGuy, @Adam: ah yes... sorry about that... thanks for the edit Adam.  Couple other small corrections made - probably one or two more needed ;-).

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answer, that was very helpful.

Comment: @NewGuy: no worries... have fun with it.

Answer (score 1):

Open file named `foo1` for writing, write it's contents, and close file.

Comment: The actual way the shell works is far more complicated for reasons you don't want to think about. This is the easy path that  accomplishes what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be tying the output logic with the command logic, which is something that will not work so well once you have more than one command. Once you have processed the line, first write the logic of echo as in "copy its parameters to `output`" and then decide what to do with `output` (write to file or print to screen).

Of course this is a very basic approach of writing a shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<fstream>` in a C program; it is a C++ header.

You'll need to use `<stdio.h>` and you'll need to use `fprintf()` rather than just `printf()`.  You open a file ('foo1') and write to that instead of to standard output.  So, you'll have a 'current output file', which you can direct to standard output by default, but to other files on demand.